# Azure APIM: Send a client certificate with send-request mode

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is it possible in azure apim to use the policy "send-request mode" to send a certificate with the request?

```
<send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="" timeout="seconds" ignore-error="true">
    <set-url></set-url>
    <set-method>GET</set-method>
    <set-header name="" exists-action="override">
        <value></value>
    </set-header>
    <set-body></set-body>
</send-request>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible in azure apim to use the policy "send-request mode" to send a certificate with the request?

In short, it's possible.

The [send-request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#SendRequest) policy sends the provided request to the specified URL, waiting no longer than the set timeout value.

Policy statement is as below:

```
<send-request mode="new|copy" response-variable-name="" timeout="60 sec" ignore-error
="false|true">
  <set-url>...</set-url>
  <set-method>...</set-method>
  <set-header name="" exists-action="override|skip|append|delete">...</set-header>
  <set-body>...</set-body>
  <authentication-certificate thumbprint="thumbprint" />
</send-request>
```

Use the [`authentication-certificate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-authentication-policies#ClientCertificate) policy to authenticate with a backend service using client certificate. The certificate needs to be **installed into API Management first and is identified by its thumbprint**.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that before, but I just had to move it to the bottom of the send-request mode.